# Android: How to pipe stream between rfcomm socket and Pppd with notty option

Tags: android, sockets, tty, android-bluetooth, pppd

I would like to run pppd on a bluetooth socket (BluetoothSocket createRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID uuid) ) on Android.
BluetoothSocket provides just inputstream and outputstream...And pppd normally requires ttyname, but seen that pppd has "notty" option with that option pppd opens its own pty...Does anybody know, how can I pipe the pppd's standard input and output with notty option to the bluetooth socket at android?...or any other idea?